# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (cv2, template matching)

Tags: python, typeerror, opencv, template-matching

I'm trying to use cv2 for template matching on a screen recording, but am running into an error that is telling me:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Source Code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import pandas

def screen_record(): 
    last_time = time.time()
    template = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Bran\\Pictures\\ovw_focus_point.jpg',-1)
    while(True):
        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1080)))
        print((time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()
        img = cv2.imread('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        print(res)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen_record()
```

Hoping someone can help!

Comment: `imshow` doesn't return anything, from the documentation, hence the error.

Comment: I've adjusted my code and change it to imread() instead of imshow(), but am now getting a new error. I've edited the question accordingly.